# get the value from a method in another class

Tags: java, android, methods

Sorry for this beginner question, but being very new to java, I can't figure out how to get value from a method in another file.

Here is my code fragment:
First, I have defined a string and used it inside a class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.menu_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(date);
                    showDateDialog();   //**I want this showDateDialogue to update mTextMessage**//
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.menu_location);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

    public void showDateDialog() {
    DialogFragment CalFragment = new CalFragment();
    CalFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    date = "Hello";
    }
}
```

where CallFragement is in another class:

```
public class CalFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
        String strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);
    }
}
```

So, Basically, I want to use the value of this `strDate` in the `mTextMessage`! But, I am very very new to java and though this type of question is very common in SO, I can't figure out a solution.

Kindly Help.

**UPDATE**
Hi, though I understand its a trivial question, but I have managed to move only a little in last 5 hour. I humbly request you to help a bit. Here is my updated code:

**MainCativity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements CalFragment.OnDateSelected{

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.menu_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(date);
                    showDateDialog();
                    mTextMessage.setText(date);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.menu_location);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

    public void showDateDialog() {
    DialogFragment CalFragment = new CalFragment();
    CalFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    date = "Hello";
    }
}
```

and

**CalFragment.java**

```
public class CalFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    OnDateSelected mcallback;
    public interface OnDateSelected {
        public void NewStrDate(String strDate);
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
        String strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);
        mcallback.NewStrDate(strDate);
    }
}
```

and this is giving error:

```
Error:(16, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method NewStrDate(String) in OnDateSelected
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. In particular, every code snippet should be inside a method which is in a class.

Comment: Did you ever consider intra-fragment communication using interfaces?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: The full class is updated. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Beginner tip try to study [Java OOPs Concepts](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-oops-concepts)

Comment: You are getting closer. However, the first code snippet still has compiler errors because there is no class.

Comment: Additionally, `mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` does not seem relevant to the question. Please read the link I gave in my first comment.

Comment: Google for something like "communicate between fragment and activity"

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: My mistake. Class added. But, `mOnNavigation...`  is from android's dependence. Possibly not relevant. But, given the structure, I can not compile it. I know, this does not adherent to MCV, but is it possible to show me some way from here?

Comment: `mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` has nothing to do with the `TextView` and `Fragment` class which you are asking about so it does not belong in the code for your question.

Comment: @BaRud read s://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: kindly please confirm if my update is visible