# get value from other class revisited

Tags: java, android, interface

My previous question [get the value from a method in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708774/get-the-value-from-a-method-in-another-class) is understandably closed because its duplicate, but I still can't find a way to solve the problem. I will be grateful if someone kindly help. I have progressed a little, but thats not enough.
First, my current code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements CalFragment.OnDateSelected{

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.menu_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    //mTextMessage.setText(date);
                    showDateDialog();
                    mTextMessage.setText(date);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.menu_location);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

    public void showDateDialog() {
    DialogFragment CalFragment = new CalFragment();
    CalFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    //date = "Hello";
    }
}
```

and

**CalFragment.java**

```
public class CalFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    OnDateSelected mcallback;
    public interface OnDateSelected {
        public void NewStrDate(String strDate);
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
        String strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);
    }
}
```

I want to supply the date from CalFragment to ShowDate dialogue, but its not working. At the present state, it shows `implements` declaration in `MainActivity` is faulty. I am reading some java tutorial, but its just my 2nd day. So kindly help a bit.

Comment: Because `CalFragment.OnDateSelected` interface declares a method `NewStrDate`, you must implement it in `MainActivity` class. Have you tried that?

Comment: No. Can you please show me what to do?

Comment: If you add a method like `    @Override
    public void NewStrDate(String strDate) {
        
    }`  in `MainActivity`, the error with `implements` declaration should go. But I would suggest, if you are just starting out with Java, you should practice on some simpler tutorial.

Comment: yes...it goes, but it still cant get the date chosen. Kindly help